# Chrome Extension: Injecting external script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension that appends a `script` tag to a page, and then uses code defined in that external script:

```
$('body').append('<script src="..."></script><script>console.log(SomeObject)</script>');
```

`SomeObject` is defined in the external script, so I should be able to access it, right? Well, I can't, as I get an "undefined" error.

I even tried using `head.js` to load the external script and execute a function after the script is loaded, to no avail.

If I open the Chrome console, I can access the damn object just fine!!!

I tried both a content script and `executeScript` inside a background page to no avail. On both, if I use `console.log(window)`, I can inspect the `window` object in the console, and `SomeObject` is nowhere to be found. If I inspect the `window` object on the Chrome console, there it is!

Are injected scripts sandboxed somehow or what gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the answer is you can't, due to security restrictions :(

I had to hack my way around it by using an `iframe` (oddly, the `iframe` **can** access its parent document).

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "...";
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // SomeObject is available!!!
});
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

I wonder why none of the other methods worked...

Answer (score 1):

I bet the script just isn't loaded when you call it right away, does this work:

```
<script src="..."></script><script>setTimeout(function() {console.log(SomeObject)}, 3000)</script>
```

Comment: I thought so too, that's why I tried using `head.js`. But I did also try your suggestion and it still won't work :(